# I get java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError when try to call a native function from my project configured with bazel

Tags: android, android-studio, java-native-interface, bazel, bazel-rules

I have created a cc_library in my bazel Build file and added the deps in android_binary rule

**Bazel BUILD:**

```
cc_library(
    name = "native_libs",
    srcs = glob([
        "app/src/main/jni/**/*.cc",
        "app/src/main/jni/**/*.h",
    ]),

)
   android_binary(
   name = "buildlib",
   srcs = glob([
        "app/src/main/java/**/*.java",
    ]),
   manifest = "app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml",
   deps = ":native_libs",
)
```

And loaded the library in the specified package as

```
static{
System.loadLibrary("buildlib");}
```

And declares and calls the native function as :

**Declaration:**

```
private static native String foo(String code);
```

**Function Call**

```
foo("Code");
```

**JNI FILE FUNCTION DECLARATION AND DEFINITION:**

```
    JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
    Java_com_example_android_(foo)( JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz, jstring code );

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_example_android_(foo)( JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz, jstring code )
{
   //some code
    return code;
}
```

The library gets loaded successfully but while function call throws an error of `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError`

How can i called the native foo() from my java file?

Comment: What does `nm native_libs.so | grep foo` produce?

Comment: Also, your question contains typos like "Jave" and "laodLibrary". I hope these are not present in your actual code?

Comment: Since your native code is C++, have you wrapped your JNI declarations/definitions in `extern "C" {}`? Also, you haven't shown us enough of your Java code for us to verify that your JNI function is named correctly.

Comment: yes.I have wrapped it under extern "C".

Comment: And the typos are not present in my actual code.

Comment: Please add the output of `nm` as I asked in the first comment, as well as the full Java package and class name.